# In case of duplicated value in variable, keep row with lowest value based on other variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have

```
> df
   ID  tti
1 118 11.2
2 118  1.4
3 118  9.2
4   9  2.7
5  12  1.2
6  12 82.8
```

There are unique and duplicated values in `df$ID`. If a value in `df$ID` is duplicated, I want to keep the row with the lowest `df$tti` value.

**Expected output**

```
> df
   ID  tti
1 118  1.4
2   9  2.7
3  12  1.2
```

I am looking for a solution in `dplyr`

Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(118L, 118L, 118L, 9L, 12L, 12L), tti = c(11.2, 
1.4, 9.2, 2.7, 1.2, 82.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `slice_min` after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice_min(tti) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID   tti
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     9   2.7
#2    12   1.2
#3   118   1.4
```

---

Or with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
df %>%
    fgroup_by(ID) %>%
    fsummarise(tti = fmin(tti))

#   ID tti
#1   9 2.7
#2  12 1.2
#3 118 1.4
```

Or another option is `roworder` (which is faster than `arrange` from `dplyr`) with `funique`

```
roworder(df, ID, tti) %>%
     funique(cols = 1)
#    ID tti
#1   9 2.7
#2  12 1.2
#3 118 1.4
```

Comment: How would one do it if `tti` was a variable in `Date` format, in order to take the most recent row ?

Comment: @Julien If it is `Date` class, the code should work as `min/max` works for the integer storage mode for Date

Answer (score 1):

By default `distinct` keeps the first row of duplicated `ID`. So if the data are sorted first by `tti` within `ID` then the first row will also be the smallest value of `tti`. By default `arrange` orders data in ascending order.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(ID, tti) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(ID, .keep_all = T)
```

**Output**

```
   ID tti
1   9 2.7
2  12 1.2
3 118 1.4
```